# Acceso a base de datos basada en servicio

Tags: c#

Buen dia a todos.

Tengo un proyecto en C# que usa una base de datos basada en servicio (local), tengo mi archivo .mdf en una determinada ruta en el equipo donde corre el sistema y hasta ahi todo bien.

La duda que tengo, es que una vez entregado el proyecto al cliente y este requiera algun mantenimiento a esta base de datos local, cual es la forma de hacer estos ajustes, ya sea agregar registros en ciertas tablas de control o actualizar determinada información que el usuario no puede hacer mediante el sistema.

Lo unico que se me ocurre es que me este enviando estos archivos mdf, hacer los cambios y planchar el mdf actualizado. ¿Hay alguna otra forma?

Comment: Por que no mejor le instalas un sql express local, con el que no tienes que pagar licencias, y puede funcionar perfectamente el sistema, y es más sencillo de manejar

Comment: Hola Eduardo, no entiendo quien estaria pagando licencia, es decir; la solucion ya trae integrado el componente (la base de datos), considerando eso mi cliente no se preocuparia por pagar una licencia, el solo corre el sistema y la informacion estaria almacenandose en el .mdf que esta local en su equipo o al menos eso dedusco.

Comment: Lo mismo con una base de datos de sql express, instalas tu instancia en la maquina local y funciona igual, la ventaja que los mantenimientos a la base de datos es mas fácil, te conectas con sql server management y y haces tus consultas

Comment: La licencia me refiero a que es la versión gratis de sql server, y por que hay otras versiones que son de pago